# Duplicate Custom Post inside another Custom post in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

Suppose I have a Custom post named Courses which is a custom post and inside Course, there are lessons, quizzes, and assignments. All are custom posts types.

I want to click on a Button specific to that Course and the Course will be duplicated with all the inner lessons, quizzes, and assignments.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be using a custom taxonomy for the sub-posts (inner lessons, quizzes, and assignments) and have your custom post display a feed from that taxonomy.

So for example lets say you had a course called 'Math 101' you could create a category called 'Math 101' and assign that category to the appropriate inner lessons, quizzes, and assignments.

In your post set up a post feed and set only items from the 'Math 101' category.

Get the plugin called 'duplicate post' (very handy), once installed you will see a 'clone' option in your "all posts".

If you clone your course the news feed will be repeated without having to recreate all the sub-posts.

This method does not actually create a copy of the sub-posts, but by using a taxonomy you can easily filter all the assignments etc by category>select all>clone and then from there (they all become drafts) you could bulk change the category to something else (ie.: 'math 101).

Hope that helps...